# Is there a list of suggested hardware specs for trying Ubuntu Openstack?

Tags: cloud, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

[Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Download | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) mentions needing 7 computers with two hard disks and at least two with dual nics.  However, it doesn't mention any CPU/storage requirements, nor does it say what these seven will do.

Does anyone know what services each of the initial seven required computers runs?  I'm looking at building out a test environment, but want to make sure that I have the correct hardware the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the OpenStack Autopilot in LDS 15.01, any 3 servers with IPMI will do, as long as they have 2 disks and at least one of them has 2 NICs (this isn't counting the LDS or MAAS machines).

In the most general sense, three servers that are [Ubuntu certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/) will be enough, or if not certified, a BMC supported by MAAS is required (IPMI being the most common choice).

That's for building your cloud. As far as to what your cloud can host, the resources - number of instances you can start, storage space available, etc, will depend on the specs of the hardware you use to build your cloud. You should have hardware appropriate to your intended usage.

Comment: Updated answer to the 15.01 Landscape release.

Answer (score 2):

CPU and storage requirements are not mentioned because it varies greatly. Generally speaking, your cloud will deploy just fine on server-class hardware that meets the two disks and two NICs requirement.

The resources - number of instances you can start, storage space available, etc, will depend on the specs of the hardware you use to build your cloud. You should have hardware appropriate to your intended usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a "feeling" for openstack, try devstack on a single machine. I also deployed Openstack on two machines before - one was doing all management, the other one the computing. Their load is quite low (but they are also pretty powerful).

You can also try Ubuntu's "openstack" package, which can create simpler single node and multi-node configurations which are more realistic than devstack's "all in one" approach - which is good to see if your patch compiles, but has little connection with operational reality.